# Stopping scroll on a specific page when LinkedIn scraping - python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scroll, linkedin-api

I am trying to webscrape jobs on LinkedIn based on url and the specific number of jobs. The code below uses infinite scrolling and scrolls until page 39, this creates 1000 elements in my 'jobs; lost but I only want 500. How can I make it stop so that it only scrolls to so that I have 500 elements.

```
url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords=Python%20%28Programming%20Language%29&location=Canada&geoId=101174742&position=1&pageNum=0'
time.sleep(2)
no_of_jobs = 500

driver = 'location of driver'

driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(url)

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1.5

i = 2
while i <= int(no_of_jobs/25) + 1:
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height

    i = i + 1

    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/main/section[2]/button').click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        pass
        time.sleep(2)


    job_lists = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'jobs-search__results-list')
    jobs = job_lists.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')  # return a list

    time.sleep(5)
```

```
Thanks
 

I know it is because my code is asking it to infinite scroll but when I had the code below, the program would run to the bottom of one page and then load the next page and scroll all the way up and start again and do that for every page.
```

```
i = 2
while i <= int(no_of_jobs/25)+1:
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
    i = i+1
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/main/section[2]/button').click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        pass
        time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to scroll down while it's possible and only then extract jobs from resulting page.

Try to extract jobs after every scroll down and add `break` statement when you reach 500 jobs.

Also `pass` here is unnecessary:

```
except:
    pass
    time.sleep(2)
```

Your code should be like this:

```
def extract_jobs(driver):
    job_lists = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'jobs-search__results-list')
    return job_lists.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')  # return a list


jobs = []
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    # Scroll down
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    
    # Extract jobs
    jobs = extract_jobs(driver)

    # Check if we have reached 500
    if len(jobs) >= 500:
        break

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

# Get you jobs here
...
another_method(jobs)
...
```

Comment: I am still new to this so I am not sure how to extract jobs after every scroll